# Object Mapper mapping for a particular class during http calls

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, jackson

Is there a way where we can add ObjectMapper for a particular class through annotation.

```
@JsonRootName("employee")
public class Sample implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String id;
    // Getters and setters 
}
```

In the RestController i have RequestMapping and a method like:-

```
 @ResponseBody
 public Sample (@RequestBody Sample sample){
 //some logic
 return sample;
}
```

My input payload to this will be like

```
    {
      "employee":{
            "name":"abcd",
            "id":"1234"
        }
    }
```

My desired output would be

```
{
    "name":"abcd",
    "id":"1234"
}
```

1)Is there a way i can use the same class to fulfill the input and the output.

2) I have added @JsonRootName at the top of the class which requires ObjectMapper's Serialization feature enable to WRAP_ROOT_VALUE like :-

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

where this can be added to reflect in only this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just leave the default serialization behavior?  Then, at deserialization you would still pull out the "employee" wrapper, but at serialization you would write it without the wrapper.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

With your input, I got the desired serialization output:

```
{"name":"abcd","id":"1234"}
```

**EDIT**

As for where to put this code, I'd recommend a singleton or class with static methods that handle your (de)serialization.  You could have two different mappers than perform the "normal" or "wrapped" behavior.  Here's an outline of the static method approach:

```
public class SerializationUtil {
    private static ObjectMapper normalObjectMapper;
    private static ObjectMapper wrappedObjectMapper;

    static {
        /* configure different (de)serialization strategies */
        normalObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        wrappedObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        wrappedObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        wrappedObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    }

    public static <T> T normalDeserialize(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        return normalObjectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    }

    public static String normalSerialize(Object bean) throws Exception {
        return normalObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
    }

    public static <T> T deserializeWrappedObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        return wrappedObjectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    }

    public static String serializeWrappedObject(Object bean) throws Exception {
        return wrappedObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
    }
}
```

The benefit of this method is it allows the caller to decide the serialization behavior.  So if there are portions of your code where you need to handle it differently you can call another method.  Note that the wrapping/unwrapping are both enabled.  So to get your desired behavior, you would call these methods like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bean bean = SerializationUtil.deserializeWrappedObject(jsonInput, Bean.class);
    String jsonOutput = SerializationUtil.normalSerialize(bean);
}
```

If this does not appeal to you, you could alternatively detect the special case and handle it in the same method call:

```
public static <T> T deserialize(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    if (clazz instanceof Bean) {
        return wrappedObjectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } else {
        return normalObjectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: My question also asks where to put this object mapper code because if i create a bean it will apply to the whole project. But i only want deserilisation in this Sample class and not in any other class.

Comment: @sunder I updated my answer.  Is that what you are looking for?